# Dropping articles: "I have a little brother and little sister." - is this correct?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, transatlantic-differences, conjunction-reduction, esl

I teach ESL online through a company which provides materials. One sentence given is

"I have a little brother and little sister."

When I read this aloud to the student, I automatically added "a" little sister. Can anyone tell me if it is ok to drop the second article "a" in the original sentence?

**Edited to add**: I wonder if there is any US English / British English distinction here? I'm British.

(I've googled this question but can't find any info on it, it's hard to define the problem. But I searched for both sentences in quotes and the one with two articles has about double the number of search results as the original with the missing article.)

thanks, Rob

Comment: No, do not drop *a* here.   If you do, then the listener may think that you are giving two descriptions of the same person: that person is both your little brother and your little sister.  For example, in "I have a little brother and best friend" I will guess that the little brother is also the best friend.

Comment: Most native speakers would probably say *I have [a younger brother and sister.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+younger+brother+and+sister%22) There are dozens of instances of ***a little brother and sister*** in Google Books, but only 2 instances of ***a little brother and a little sister*** and just one ***a little brother and little sister***. Syntactically theyu're all fine, and in practice would always mean exactly the same.

Comment: @GEdgar: *I have a little brother and best friend* sounds to me like a non-idiomatic "zeugma".

Answer (score 1):

In comments FumbleFingers wrote:

> Most native speakers would probably say *I have [a younger brother and sister.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+younger+brother+and+sister%22)* There are dozens of instances of ***a little brother and sister*** in Google Books, but only 2 instances of ***a little brother and a little sister*** and just one ***a little brother and little sister***. Syntactically they're all fine, and in practice would always mean exactly the same.

> *I have a little brother and best friend* sounds to me like a non-idiomatic "zeugma".

Comment: Interesting that the Google Books instances are the opposite of Google search results instances.

Comment: I'd say that "I have a little brother and a little sister" is standard and formal,  "I have a little brother and sister" is standard and not so formal, and "I have a little brother and little sister" sounds at best unidiomatic. Try it with "I have a big dog and a big house", where the referents are pretty disparate. Omitting the second 'a' sounds near outlandish.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment GEdgar wrote:

> No, do not drop *a* here.   If you do, then the listener may think that you are giving two descriptions of the same person: that person is both your little brother and your little sister.  For example, in "I have a little brother and best friend" I will guess that the little brother is also the best friend.